LIBUSB error: usb.core.NoBackendError occurs in .exe file (created with auto-py-to-exe), but not in Python script
I'm working on Windows 11 system connected to a device through libusbwin32 driver. I have installed pyusb and libusb, and libusb path is added to Windows environment as:
\venv\Lib\site-packages\libusb\_platform\_windows\x64
and
\venv\Lib\site-packages\libusb\_platform\_windows\x32
I could run the python script from PyCharm IDE and access the device and display its output.
However, when I converted my Python script to exe file using auto-py-to-exe, and then run this exe file, it shows below error:
File "usb\core.py", line 1297, in find
usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available
I have also tried to change Windows environment to C:Windows\....
Still this problem persists.
Also I have referred this pyusb-backend-not-accessible this script works before exe conversion, after that I get error.
What is it I'm missing while I'm converting my python script to exe using auto-py-to-exe?

Have you specified anywhere to include the libusb0.dll file?

No, we have not specified libusb0.dll file in our script. We didn't need to. But it's exe file shows no backend error.

To be clear, the dll location needs to be specified as part of the exe creation. I think it is the Additional Files setting with auto-py-to-exe

We tried, but didn't work. But your suggestion did help us. We tried in path and binary in Advanced settings. Its working !!!

I suggest you write up what got it working so that others can learn. You can accept your own answer as the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

ya sure .. i will upload the answer

We have found the solution, we need to manually enter the libusb dlls in Advanced--> add binary and libusb folder paths in Advanced-->paths.
auto-py-to-exe app will not automatically access libusb package. So based on your system you need to enter parameters with correct locations. You can see in the image

